# Create a git repository that contains another git repository

Tags: git, version-control

I have created a bare git repo (lets call it repo #1) and cloned it.

- In the clone (repo #2) I have created several folders, one of which I have decided to make a git repo (repo #3).
- When I commit to repo #2, everything runs as expected exept that repo #3 is ignored (the .git folder, the files commit).

How can I add repo #3 to repo #2 so that when I push repo #2 to repo #1, I can make a seperate clone of repo #1 in which I can also access the history etc. of repo #3?

In other words. How do I create a git repository that contains another git repository?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't do that. Metadata under .git/ is changed during repo lifetime and that changes not necessarily mean "changes in the content" that should be committed: simple `git repack` changes files under .git but that changes should not be committed. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I am using the parent repo (#2) to facilitate easy backing up of the folders that it contains which includes repo #3. Everything is stored on a USB drive and this way I can easily push a backup of everything to my backup location (repo #1).

It seems that I will just have to manually copy the folders to back them up for now.

Comment: If everything you want is just a backup of all repositories (and working copies), then you might just use something that doesn't know anything about git ant it's structure, for example mercurial or bazaar.

As wRAR said it would add lots of stuff that you dont need, but if you just want a backup then it might be ok. But you could also just write a script that goes through every repository on your stick and pushes it to the server.

Answer (score 13):

I don't know how to do exactly what you are suggesting, but sub-modules probably come close (or as close as you are going to get). Here is a decent tutorial:

http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/GitSubmoduleTutorial

Answer (score 2):

see [git submodule](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)

i’ve never used it, so all i can do is post a link …

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a GIT pro by any means, but i think you are referring to git submodules

```
git submodule --help
```

Answer (score 2):

In your container repository root folder, just do:

```
git submodule add https://github.com/yourusername/containedrepo.git containedrepo
```

This will clone the `containedrepo` inside the `/containedrepo` directory. From now on, you should not make changes in the `/containedrepo` directory, but rather make changes in the `containedrepo` and then pull them. When you pull the main container repository, it will also pull all submodules repository, e.g. `containedrepo.git`.

Here's a great tutorial : https://github.com/NebuPookins/git-submodule-tutorial