# How to I combine two separate Git repositories?

Tags: git

I have cloned a [git repo](http://github.com/kerspoon/emacs-starter-kit) which has my emacs config files in. I would like to add [pylookup](http://github.com/tsgates/pylookup) in a subdirectory. What is the correct way to do this?

Below are the options I can think of.

---

1. If I clone it into `~/.emacs.d/pylookup/` and add that folder to my emacs repo, will that update properly when I do:

   ```
   cd ~/.emacs.d/pylookup/
   git pull
   cd ~/.emacs.d
   git commit -a -m "updates to pylookup"
   git push
   ```

   i.e. when I pull those changes on my other machines will I have the new version of pylookup?
2. Do I simply get my emacs repo to ignore `pylookup/*` and update it on every machine whenever pylookup is updated. This would get annoying if there was a few repo's and a few machines but I can live with it.
3. Is there some smart tricks with `git submodule`. If so could you provide an explanation I didn't really understand the [documentation](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/GitSubmoduleTutorial). How would I pull changes for emacs and for pylookup.
4. Do I go with answer 2 but make a script to update all sub-repos. If I did that I could run that once on each machine every time pylookup changed.

---

Couple of possible related posts.

- [Combining multiple git repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277029/combining-multiple-git-repositories)
- [Create a git repository that contains another git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404232/create-a-git-repository-that-contains-another-git-repository)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you create a  [Git submodule](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule):

```
$ git submodule add git://github.com/tsgates/pylookup.git pylookup
$ git submodule init pylookup
$ git submodule update pylookup
```

Let's say there are some changes to pylookup and you want to get them:

```
$ cd pylookup
$ git pull origin master
$ cd ..
$ git add pylookup
$ git commit -m "Track new commit of pylookup"
```

Comment: Good answer. What happens on my other computer when I do pull the emacs changes. i.e. do I have to update pylookup on every machine.

Answer (score 0):

I used subtree merge with a similar problem - http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging. Something like:

```
$ git remote add -f pylookup /path/to/pylookup
$ git merge -s ours --no-commit pylookup/master
$ git read-tree --prefix=pylookup/ -u pylookup/master
$ git ci -m "merging pylookup into pylookup subdirectory"
```

Good guide here: http://jasonkarns.com/blog/merge-two-git-repositories-into-one

Comment: Is "git ci" an alias for git commit? It would be better to avoid non standard alias.

Comment: It is. Thanks for the heads up